# How do I run a regression where the each treated lot has different matched control lots?

Tags: r, regression, matching, subset

I am attempting to run a diff-in-diff regression where each treated variable (lot) is matched with a number of untreated controls lots. I have created a list of eligible control lots based on location relative to each individual treated lot, from which 14 control lots are randomly selected. I have 70 some treated lots and each has a list of 14 matched control lots. My problem comes when I try to run my regression.

I can run a regression where all treated lots and all control lots are used without specific matching:

```
m1 <- glm.nb(y ~ treated_group*is_post, data = df)
```

I can run a regression with one treated lot and it's 14 control lots:

```
m2 <- glm.nb(y ~ treated_group*is_post, data = filter(df, lot_name  
                  %in% control$combo[[2]])))
```

where **control$combo** is a data frame where I matched the lots and the **combo** column is just a list of a treated lot name and the 14 matched control lot names. The **[[2]]** is just because the  second row is the first lot in the list that is a treated lot.

However, I am struggling to write a regression using all 70 treated lots but only using each matched list of control lots. I suppose I am asking if there is a way to combine all 70 regressions or somehow write a subset for the data such that the control lots being used are the ones matched to each treated lot.

Edit:
per Thomas' advice

df:

| lot_name | year | quarter | cpy | cpm | treated_group | is_post |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lot1 | 13 | 1 | 47 | 11 | 0 | 0 |
| lot1 | 13 | 2 | 47 | 15 | 0 | 0 |
| lot1 | 13 | 3 | 47 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| lot1 | 13 | 4 | 47 | 14 | 0 | 0 |
| lot1 | 14 | 5 | 53 | 10 | 0 | 1 |
| lot1 | 14 | 6 | 53 | 16 | 0 | 1 |
| lot1 | 14 | 7 | 53 | 12 | 0 | 1 |
| lot1 | 14 | 8 | 53 | 15 | 0 | 1 |
| lot2 | 13 | 1 | 38 | 9 | 1 | 0 |
| lot2 | 13 | 2 | 38 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| lot2 | 13 | 3 | 38 | 11 | 1 | 0 |
| lot2 | 13 | 4 | 38 | 8 | 1 | 0 |
| lot2 | 14 | 5 | 41 | 12 | 1 | 1 |
| lot2 | 14 | 6 | 41 | 11 | 1 | 1 |
| lot2 | 14 | 7 | 41 | 9 | 1 | 1 |
| lot2 | 14 | 8 | 41 | 9 | 1 | 1 |

control:

| lot_name | treated | possible_controls | count | combo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lot1 | 0 | NA | NA | NA |
| lot2 | 1 | lot1,lot5,lot13,... | 64 | lot2,lot13,... |

So the **possible_controls** would be the list of all matched control lots, **count** is the number matched, and **combo** is the list of the treated lot plus the selected control lots.

Comment: Welcome. This seems more like a programming problem. First, is `control$combo` a separate data frame? If so, why not merge the two data frames based upon the lot name? If I'm missing something let me know. It's hard to offer suggestions without seeing a subset of your data.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBilach , and you may be right about it just being a programming issue so I reposted on Stack Overflow. I have added sample subsets of my data frames per your comment. I am not sure how merging the data frames would solve the subset issue? What I am looking at is crime around parks, and the matched controls are parks in the same district but different neighborhood of the city.  Also, sorry about the late response, had to merge the original guest profile with a new one to comment.

Comment: After looking at your profile @ThomasBilach, you may be familiar with the paper that I am kinda trying to follow: "Did community greening reduce crime? Evidence from New Haven, CT, 1996–2007" by Locke, et all. They subset their control lots such that only ones that met specific conditions were used in the DiD for each treated lot. fs.fed.us/nrs/pubs/jrnl/2017/nrs_2017_locke_001.pdf

Comment: I am familiar with the study. I will try and address it on SO unless someone else is already on it. If you have any questions about the model itself or how to interpret it then follow-up here.

Comment: So right now you have a data frame containing all lots throughout the city; only 70 of the lots will be greened. But what you want is one data frame which only includes the 14 controls per treated lot. Thus, your final data frame will include 70 treated lots and 910 control lots. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, the lots I am studying are community adopted parks, and the control lots are parks left to be maintained by the city. The goal being to find a connection between community engagement and crime reduction. But the data frame you are suggesting is correct, except some control lots are used for multiple treated lots so there is only a total of 290 or so. And each has crime data by year and month and type (violent vs property). I am trying to follow the bit in the paper where they restrict candidate control block faces for each treated face by distance, and implement that in my regression.

Comment: Locke et al. (2017) tested whether greening on street segments/community parks lowered crime, relative to the non-greened street segments. In your setting, you're comparing 'community-greened' parks with a matched group of parks maintained by the city, correct? The ultimate goal is to get one data frame. I wouldn't recommend running separate regressions for each treated lot, though nothing is stopping you from doing so

Comment: That is correct! I have combined the data frames. I was trying to follow their method of only using matched control lots for each individual treated lot. One reason is areas of the city I am studying (Detroit, MI) are very different from one another. The other reason is to avoid a spill-over effect. I just don't understand how to implement this in my regression in R. So regression-wise, I am not sure how to set up the equation or alter the data frame to avoid using parks too close/far as controls.